# Why HTACCESS RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} only for php and not working for html?

Tags: php, .htaccess, html, rewritecond, http-cookie

I was trying to redirect all direct access in my subfolder using this code

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !user_cookie=[^;]
RewriteRule .* http://webhost.org/ [R=301,L]
```

I realise it was working only for OHP files but not for other files like HTML.
I tried to access the link to the PHP file and it works as I planned, but when I'm accessing the other file with `.html` extension it does not redirect,
as if it was ignoring the condition of `.htaccess`.

I'm new to `.htaccess`. What am I doing wrong?

Server information:

- fresh install of Vestacp
- Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS 6 x64)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted doesn't necessarily apply to "direct" requests. It applies when a cookie is not set (ie. not sent back in the `Cookie` HTTP request header) - this is not the same thing. (Presumably you are setting a "session" cookie? However, browser's definition of a "session" varies, so these cookies can end up being more *persistent* than you expect.)

If it's "working only for PHP files but not for other files like HTML" then it's because the browser is not sending the `Cookie` HTTP request header for requests to your PHP files - for some reason. Maybe it's the PHP files that are "incorrect" and the `Cookie:` header should be getting sent - like for HTML files?

The difference between your PHP and HTML files could be down to caching, domain and/or URL-path. This has nothing to do with your `.htaccess` script.

To check for "direct access" it is more usual to check for an empty `Referer` header. However, this (and any) method you use is not going to be entirely reliable.